Server Question
Curious so I’m just asking.  Looking to setup a simple Ubuntu server, mostly for media (music & some video.) But I would still like to use the install from time to time to try out different O/S on VMware or Virtual Box.  Will that be a problem?

Will that be a problem? asks for 100% certainty, so it is not answerable, because there are many unknowns ... on the other hand, Could that be a problem? is answerable
